# react/nodejs: Receiving value from a select dropdown to send it to the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm having a select dropdown in my react frontend like this

```html
<select name="level" value={level} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control">
             <option>Begineer</option>
             <option>Intermediate</option>
             <option>Advanced</option>
            </select>
```

I'm handling this value as req.body in my backend. My handleChange function is simply

```js
handleChange(event) {
  const state = this.state;
  state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    state
  });
}
```

When i submit the form, this value does not gets submitted. I'm also intitializing this value in my constructor function. What can i do in this case?

Comment: `const state = this.state;` does not create a copy of `this.state`, which means you're manipulating `this.state`. Anyway, what is `{level}`?

Comment: `{level}` is the string value entered as a `req.body` on backend. It should recieve the appropriate level i.e. Begineer, Intermediate or Advanced from dropdown.

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
  this.setState(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to ad the value to your options

```
  <option value="Begineer">Begineer</option>
```

second of all never mutate the state object directly without set state 
like this

```
  state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
```

instead

```
 let objToUpdate = {...state};
objToUpdate[event.target.name]=  event.target.value
this.setState(objToUpdate)
```

this should solve your issue

Comment: An `option` without `value` has its `innerHTML` as value.

Comment: And, without hassling too much you can set the state like this `this.setState( { [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value } )`